# Images not displaying in cart page

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, shopping-cart

[image]ref:[mages not displaying in cart or mini cart](http://mages%20not%20displaying%20in%20cart%20or%20mini%20cart)

I have created one custom attribute `imageurl` to import product image url. Product images are loading from external url. Images displaying in product list and product detailed page. But simple products are not displaying in cart and mini cart page.. What can be the issue?

Comment: Do you use https in cart?

Comment: sorry... I didnt get you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit `/app/design/frontend/PACKAGE/THEME/template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml` and use below code to get an `ImageUrl` :

```
<img src="<?php echo Mage::getModel("catalog/product")->load($_item->getProduct()->getId())->getImageurl(); ?>" />
```

Comment: no .. its not working... configurable product images are displaying but not simple product images

Comment: Are you sure, this simple product has `imageurl` attribute set ?

Comment: This is just a logic that you need to place in appropriate template. Just check/debug for simple product cart template (Can use Path hints), and place above code.